# Make arrow head shape symmetric regardless of the angle of the arrow in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code yields the figure below. The shape of the arrowhead is dependent on the angle of the arrow. How can I make all of the arrow heads the same symmetric shape? I am asking specifically for Python 3 but general solutions are welcome.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.arrow(0, 0, .5, .5, head_width = .1)
plt.arrow(0, 0, .2, .5, head_width = .1)
plt.arrow(0, 0,  0, .5, head_width = .1)
plt.axis((-1, 1, -1 ,1))
plt.show()
```

[image: arrow head demo]

Comment: Hmm, I don't have specific answer to this but an alternate could be to use `plt.annotate`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible with `plt.arrow`.
I guess the reason `plt.arrow` still exists is purely for backwards compatibility. Arrows are better produced by `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch`. The easiest way to get such `FancyArrowPatch` in your plot is via `plt.annotate`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prop = dict(arrowstyle="-|>,head_width=0.4,head_length=0.8",
            shrinkA=0,shrinkB=0)

plt.annotate("", xy=(.5,.5), xytext=(0,0), arrowprops=prop)
plt.annotate("", xy=(.2,.5), xytext=(0,0), arrowprops=prop)
plt.annotate("", xy=(.0,.5), xytext=(0,0), arrowprops=prop)

plt.axis((-1, 1, -1 ,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Arrows are currently a bit underdocumented, but there is still [a plan to write up](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11350) some complete tutorial or guide.

Answer (score -2):

Adjusting the plot with an equal axis aspect ratio is useful.

```
plt.axis('equal')
```